# Nginx same url but different directory to serve file?

Tags: nginx, web

i am trying to serve two different file based on the user agent.
exampl:- 
if i go to **m.abc.com** from mobile device i want to serve `mobile/index.php`
else `desktop/index.php`,but url should remain same.

in apache i have done like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(android|blackberry|mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|ipad|opera\smobile|palmos|webos|bing|UCWEB) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\/report\/\.*)
RewriteRule !^desktop_site/ /desktop_site%{REQUEST_URI}  [L]
```

how can i achieve this in Nginx?

Comment: You have to use nginx rewrite module. please refer to docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html